# How to get login cookie on tiktok

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, apify, tiktok

I want to scrape tiktok comments on [apify](https://console.apify.com/actors/GdWCkxBtKWOsKjdch), but the settings tells me that i need to provide cookies to log in as a normal TikTok user (you can copy with a Chrome plugin like 'EditThisCookie').
[Click here to see Scraping Comments description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m2OB.png)

I have downloaded and installed EditThisCookie Extension, but i can't find any cookies that represents login cookie :

[EditThisCookie #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Gwt.png)

[EditThisCookie #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i43tj.png)

Does any one know to get the login cookies value ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of Apify's TikTok scraper. Click on the **export button** in the EditThisCookie extension, this will copy the whole cookies to your clipboard and then paste them to the
`loginCookies` input field.

This is necessary because TikTok comments are available only after login. A captcha blocks manual login, so injecting cookies from the logged session is the easiest solution. Don't forget to **log in first before copying the cookies**.